# Displaying file path ending in html file field

Tags: javascript, html

Assume we have `<input type="file" name="my_file>`. If I click choose/select (or whatever my browser displays) and select a file, then the field displays file's path.

If file path is long, I cannot see its ending:

If file path is `/very/long/path/to/my/file/my_file.png` then only the beginning of the file name will be shows at once `/very/long/path...` and then file field ends.

I would like to do something (with javascript, preferrably) so that the browser would shows file name ending instead of beginning: `...y/file/my_file.png`.

Does any universal solution for all browsers exist?

Comment: In Chrome it only shows the file name. FF and IE show a textbox next to the button so you can see the full path. So my question is: what browser are you using that it shows a truncated full path?

Comment: Yes, it shows, but in Opera you have to scroll. I'd like to the the file name initially instead of the beginning of the path.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [FileList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/FileList) API. They have a pretty extensive example you may find useful.

Comment: Displaying file name next to the file field is one of the possible solutions, however it is already displayed in some of the browsers. In FF and opera there is an input field in which the file path is written and i'm looking for a way to scroll the input field value with JS.

Comment: hide the input and click it programmatically with a button. then take the value of the name and display it. easy.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, have a look at this plugin - https://github.com/ajaxray/bootstrap-file-field

It will display the file input field as a bootstrap button and will show selected file names beautifully. Additionally, you can set various restrictions using simple data-attributes. e,g, `data-file-types="image/jpeg,image/png"` will restrict selecting file types except jpg and png images.